# What would the short term consequences of the sun disappearing?

Tags: internal-consistency

In my world gods are embodiments of things in nature like the sun or a mountain. Due to certain events the god representing the sun got killed with the plot being creating a new sun before the world freezes.

What i wish to ask is how would the world change over the course of a week(I plan to finish the plot in a week.) other than the world becoming cold?

Comment: You have 48h at best before anything not located within a large body of water is frozen to death. Anything outside of the tropics, 24h. No land animal survives this outside of deep caves, and only plants that are already in winter mode and covered by two meters of snow.

Comment: Highly related if not even duplicate https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2629/30492

Comment: Also please note that reality check shall not be used as only tag of a question

Comment: Oh, and anything located close to a body of water gets blown into it by terrible storms, as the air above land cools much faster.

Comment: Have you tried a Google search before asking your question? You will find a lot there. The thing is, you are asking a question that could be interpreted in many, many ways. If you could spend some time thinking and researching about it yourself, you will find that you don't need help to come up with most of the consequences. If you then come back to ask for help specifically for the aspects you can't do on your own, you are only really starting to utilize this stack exchange correctly. You then go from asking: "build my world for me" to "help me build my world"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If only the sun's light went out, how long would it take for all living things to die out?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/100211/if-only-the-suns-light-went-out-how-long-would-it-take-for-all-living-things-t) -- not quite the same question but the answers should be close enough.

Comment: [Mandatory XKCD What If](https://what-if.xkcd.com/49/).

Answer (score 1):

> What i wish to ask is how would the world change over the course of a week(I plan to finish the plot in a week.) other than the world becoming cold?

Other than getting cold it will get dark.  That may sound trivial but animals are mostly hardwired to operate on a diurnal cycle of 24 hours and their body clocks get totally out of whack (to use a technical term) when you deprive them of a regular day-night cycle.

For humans, ignoring the cold, a couple of days of this will have psychological consequences for most people.  Your sleep pattern goes wrong for a couple of days and you're soon suffering.  Humans do not thinks rationally or well when their sleep pattern is disturbed.  Daylight is an essential ingredient in your psychological well being.  This has implications for a break down in the so-called social fabric.

Now it gets cold, and this has practical consequences.  Frost won't clear and will build up.  Snow will fall and won't stop (at least in a week).  So transport infrastructure, mostly dependent on ice-free and snow-free conditions, will break down rapidly.  In some countries they can cope better than others with this, but in most temperate climates and particularly in countries where snow is a rarity this will be devastating.

That has severe implications for food and fuel supplies.  By the end of a week stocks would be running out - you live in a world largely based around daily-demand with constant delivery streams.

A week is not long enough to cripple industry, but a week is long enough to see supply chains broken.

It would take a great deal longer than a week to design a replacement infrastructure (if that's possible) capable of supporting transport in a "Big Freeze" like this.  It would perhaps take six months to a year to develop the required infrastructure and implement it well enough to sustain major populations reasonably.  This is beyond the time scale of your story.

Darkness brings other things - criminals.  It's not that they don't operate in daylight, of course, but they *like* the dark.  Criminals, particularly those robbing food stores and other items for resale on a black market, will increase.  Everywhere martial law would be introduced, but martial law won't necessarily stop this increase, but will blunt it a little.

Legally states of emergency would be declared everywhere.  Civil liberties would be taking a back seat.

Politically people won't necessarily believe that this is a permanent state of affairs.  This will complicate handling the problems and may result in major political unrest.  There are even people daft enough to think their governments are responsible for this state of affairs or that they can do something to turn the Sun on.  This would create some unrest, how much is difficult to say.  Again martial law would complicate this and not necessarily solve the problem - if history proves anything it's that troops on the street doesn't generally stop crime or protest.

So rapid political chaos.  In some places the military would forcibly take over - maybe to try and do the right thing, maybe just as an expedient because in some places the military are just looking for an excuse anyway.

Humans are into the blame game.  A lot of effort will be made trying to find out who to blame (i.e. your political enemies are to blame - make everyone else believe that), and not as much will be done to try and cope.  Look at Brexit - lots of "whose fault is this" in the UK and very little "here's a sensible plan"  Unfortunately that approach is not unique to the UK - lots of countries fail to deal with problems and play the blame game.  The first week in a lot of democracies will be spent playing the blame game before the cold and dark (and possibly political necessity) finally make that pointless.

So lots of running around like headless chickens with the same end result, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the planet continues in its orbit... actually not very much, *physically* (no cataclysms or hurricanes or suchlike). The world would end - "not with a bang but a whimper".

And I suspect you don't have a full week.

Consider that everywhere on Earth the Sun does go out once every 24 hours. In those 24 hours, temperatures drop by as much as 40 K depending on cloud coverage, air temperatures and so on. Nothing really drastic happens, even though the areas that had not seen the Sun in the 12 hours prior now do. So, keeping them *without* the Sun actually introduces less energy in the system.

But that's not the full story. Consider an area at around 45° N; the air in the ecosphere averages, say, 10 degrees Celsius. The volume closest to the ground starts losing heat and, after 24-36 hours, drops below freezing; meanwhile, the dew point falls much more slowly, and saturation reaches 100%. Temperature drop decreases as water condenses out of the atmosphere, first as rain, then as snow. This will happen faster away from large bodies of water that act as heat buffers, but won't probably lead to any violent atmospheric phenomena (except that massive rains might perhaps trigger landslides?).

Nonetheless, when temperature reaches around -40 °C - which I expect by the fourth day, more or less - most plants will die or already be dead. Past that point, you have an ecological catastrophe on your hands.

The consequences of the cold and the snow and ice - no transportation, etc. - will also be much more severe than simply "stay at home". And, unless everybody knows exactly what is happening, just a single day without the Sun will lead to chaos, with people believing they're going to die (most will be right, at that) and they have nothing to lose.

Comment: In four days temperatures will reach levels usually not seeen outside the Antarctic. I have no idea how well-prepared places like Miami, Naples, Jerusalem, Riyadh, Bangkok, New Delhi or Jakarta are for Antartic temperatures, but I suspect that they aren't prepared at all; *billions* of people would die.

Comment: @AlexP exactly so. Even a drop to a balmy -20 °C would cause widespread death, since even after the Sun's return, the temperature wouldn't rise immediately back to normal.